# query that returns rows where time difference past threshold

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, join, row

this is an odd question.  i dunno if it is quite doable.

let's say i have the following table:

```
person | product  | trans  | purchase_date
-------+----------+--------+---------------
jim    | square   | aaaa   | 2013-03-04 00:01:00
sarah  | circle   | aaab   | 2013-03-04 00:02:00
john   | square   | aac1   | 2013-03-04 00:03:00
john   | circle   | aac2   | 2013-03-04 00:03:10
jim    | triangle | aad1   | 2013-03-04 00:04:00
jim    | square   | abcd   | 2013-03-04 00:05:00
sarah  | square   | efgh   | 2013-03-04 00:07:00
jim    | circle   | ijkl   | 2013-03-04 00:22:00
sarah  | circle   | mnop   | 2013-03-04 00:24:00
sarah  | square   | qrst   | 2013-03-04 00:26:00
sarah  | circle   | uvwx   | 2013-03-04 00:44:00
```

i need to know when the difference between any person's purchases between a square and a circle (or a circle and a square) have exceeded 10 minutes.  ideally, i'd like to know that difference as well, but that isn't required.

so as a result, here is what i need:

```
person | product  | trans  | purchase_date
-------+----------+--------+---------------
jim    | square   | abcd   | 2013-03-04 00:05:00
jim    | circle   | ijkl   | 2013-03-04 00:22:00
sarah  | square   | efgh   | 2013-03-04 00:07:00
sarah  | circle   | mnop   | 2013-03-04 00:24:00
sarah  | square   | qrst   | 2013-03-04 00:26:00
sarah  | circle   | uvwx   | 2013-03-04 00:44:00
```

this will run daily, so i will add a "where" clause to ensure the query doesn't get out of hand.  also, i am aware that multiple transactions could show up (say there were 20 minutes between the purchase of a circle, then 20 minutes for a square, then 20 minutes for a circle again, which would mean there were 2 instances where the time difference was over 10 minutes).

any advice?  i am on postgres 8.1.23

Comment: Why doesn't Jim's square for tran aaaa come back as well given your criteria?

Comment: @xQbert i'm fine if that happens.  there is no guarantee that squares and circles will be inserted sequentially (right word?).  but because there was not a corresponding 'circle' to go with that 'square' before jim purchased another 'square', i left it off of the list.  there should be a 1:1 of squares:circles.  if one is unmatched, i'd be glad to know.

Comment: I've got something that should work, but it'll include the result xQbert pointed out.  You would have to add transaction IDs to your result set to filter those out (which would likely be better done in code than SQL).

Comment: My first advice: Upgrade to a reasonable version of Postgres. [8.1 has reached EOL in 2010(!)](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Modern day versions have [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) making that a lot easier.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter i'd love to upgrade, but 8.1 is what we got at the moment, and it's not up to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modern day solution

With modern day Postgres (8.4 or later) you can use the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) to get a continuous numbering per group. Then you can left join to the previous and next row and see if either of them matches the criteria. Voilá.

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *
         ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY purchase_date) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  product IN ('circle', 'square')
   )
SELECT x.person, x.product, x.trans, x.purchase_date
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN x y ON y.person = x.person AND y.rn = x.rn + 1
LEFT   JOIN x z ON z.person = x.person AND z.rn = x.rn - 1
WHERE (y.product <> x.product
       AND y.purchase_date > x.purchase_date + interval '10 min')
   OR (z.product <> x.product
       AND z.purchase_date < x.purchase_date - interval '10 min')
ORDER  BY x.person, x.purchase_date;
```

[**SQLfiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/60e4a/1)

#### Solution for Postgres 8.1

I can't test this on Postgres 8.1, no surviving instance available. Tested and works on v8.4 and *should* work for you, too. [Temporary sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-createsequence.html) and temporary tables and and [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-createtableas.html) were already available.
Temporary sequence and table are only visible to you, so you can get continuous numbers even with concurrent queries.

```
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE s;

CREATE TEMP TABLE x AS
SELECT *, nextval('s') AS rn  -- get row-numbers from sequence
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  product IN ('circle', 'square')
   ORDER  BY person, purchase_date  -- need to order in a subquery first!
   ) a;
```

Then the same `SELECT` as above should work:

```
SELECT x.person, x.product, x.trans, x.purchase_date
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN x y ON y.person = x.person AND y.rn = x.rn + 1
LEFT   JOIN x z ON z.person = x.person AND z.rn = x.rn - 1
WHERE (y.product <> x.product
       AND y.purchase_date > x.purchase_date + interval '10 min')
   OR (z.product <> x.product
       AND z.purchase_date < x.purchase_date - interval '10 min')
ORDER  BY x.person, x.purchase_date;
```

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner.  this was it.  i used the 8.1 solution, and it worked great.  i shortened the query to remove the z join, as the join on the x and y gave me everything i needed.  this table gets 125k rows a day (i went back and checked), so joining it on itself was taking way too long. this did the trick.  if i'm not mistaken, the lag function could've worked as well, if i wasn't on 8.1?

Comment: Thanx for all the chicken. Your real situation is probably different. But for the question asked `z` is essential. Without it, the last row is dropped from every series of qualifying rows - as demonstrated in this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/60e4a/2).

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining the table to itself with an 'ON' clause like this:

```
SELECT a.Person, CAST((DATEDIFF(mi, b.purchaseDateb a.purchaseDate)/60.0) AS Decimal) AS TimeDiff, a.Product, b.Product FROM <TABLE> a
JOIN <TABLE> b
ON a.Person = b.Person AND b.purchaseDate > a.purchaseDate
WHERE
(a.Product = 'Circle' AND b.Product = 'Square')
OR
(a.Product = 'Square' AND b.Product = 'Circle')
```

By joining the table to itself you get rows which combine two purchases by the same person.  By limiting it to 'b.purchaseDate > a.purchaseDate' you prevent rows matching themselves.  Then you can simply check for different products purchased.

The time difference is the last tricky part.  What I included above is based on an answer I found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1188751.aspx/1).  It looks like it should work, and there's a couple of variations there you can use if what this outputs doesn't work for you.

You'll need to add a clause on the WHERE statement which uses the same DATEDIFF function to test for time > 10 minutes, but that should pose no great challenge.

Please note that this won't return exactly what you have in your question - this will include a row for Jim's first transaction as well as one for Jim's 2nd square purchase.  Both will match to the same circle, and you will get both times (ijkl-abcd AND ijkl-aaaa).  Thanks for xQbert's comment for pointing this out.

Comment: i tried this, and the query ended up running out of memory (even narrowing it down to a days worth of data).  just for anyone else's reference, the postgres way of generating the time difference (that i'm using is) abs(DATE_PART('epoch', a.purchase_date - b.purchase_date))

Comment: @jasonmclose: If you're running out of memory on that, it might be easier to pull this data out and run your analysis in code, honestly.  This query shouldn't be a massive memory hog, unless the data is HUGE.

Comment: good point.  i will up the memory and postgres and see if that helps.  the data is not that large.  we get maybe 10k data points a day.

Answer (score 0):

--Assumes

1. You want to know differences in minutes for purchase on same day.  If dates don't matter eliminate the where clause.
2. That you only want considerations of circle to square following the purchase_date, not preceding.
   .

.

```
SELECT A.person, A.product, a.Trans, A.Purchase_date, B.Purchase_date, 
hours_diff * 60 + DATE_PART('minute', B.purchase_date - A.Purchase_date ) as minuteDifference
FROM yourTable A
LEFT JOIN yourTable B 
  on A.person = B.Person 
    and ((A.product = 'square' and b.product = 'circle') 
      OR (A.Product = 'circle' and b.product = 'square'))
    and A.purchase_date <= B.Purchase_date
WHERE (A.purchase_Date::date = B.purchase_date::date OR B.purchase_date is null)
```

Null B.purchase_dates will tell you when you don't have a circle/square or square circle combo.

Comment: This, too, matches any row of the same person and a matching product, instead of only the *neighboring* row. Leads to a `CROSS JOIN` (confined to the same day by your additional condition) which is very expensive nonsense.